# Getting: ruby-2.2.0 [ missing bin/ruby ] in the terminal. What to do now?

Tags: ruby, terminal, installation, rvm

Hi when I type rvm list on the terminal I go this output:

ruby-2.2.0 [ missing bin/ruby ]

What should I do in order to set ruby properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "set ruby properly"?

Comment: what should I do in order to not obtain "ruby-2.2.0 [ missing bin/ruby ]" anymore?

Comment: Did you receive any errors, when installing ruby 2.2.0?